# Not able to update packages

Tags: r

I am trying to run SIFT analysis in R but the following message is displayed:

> Error : package or namespace load failed for ‘klaR’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> namespace ‘pillar’ 1.4.7 is being loaded, but >= 1.5.1 is required

I also updated the Pillar package, but I still get this error.
Could someone please help me understand?

Comment: try updating `klaR` package

Comment: You should edit the result of `sessionInfo()` into your question so we can see what is going on.

Comment: If you update `pillar`, restart R, and still get this error, make sure that your update of `pillar` succeeded; it is not uncommon (especially with packages with compiled C/C++/Fortran libraries) for a package to *not* be updateable after it has been loaded into R. The workaround for that is to restart R and *not* loading the package, then update it, then load it as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But the problem has not been solved yet!!(R version 4.03)